# Cannot Resolve ContextCompat in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an AlertDialogue object called dialog. I am attempting to add an icon to it. I see that this syntax is now deprecated:

```
dialog.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myImage);
```

I'm reading everywhere that this should work:

```
dialog.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.myImage));
```

However, the ContextCompat syntax is not being recognized by Android Studio. Is there something that I should be importing? Thank you.

***Update: Thank's to @Sharj for the correct answer below. I made a quick video too if you guys need a visual: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFiaO0srQro&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Migrating the app module to AndroiX will resolve other dependency also

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[ContextCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html) is part of support library v4. Have you added support library 4 to your project?

```
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
```

You can include support library to your build.gradle file under app folder if you haven't already

```
dependencies {
// other stuff here
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
// update the 23.0.0 to latest version available

}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to add support library 4. Is it a simple import statement at the top of my class? import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat

Comment: Also, which gradle file do I add the statement to? The one under build.gradle says Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong in the individual module build.gradle files.

Comment: You will find build.gradle file in your app folder.

Comment: How do I solve this with Eclipse where there are no gradle build files?  I have the V7 version of appcompat downloaded by the Android SDK Manager?  I added the android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to my project. The eclipse IDE error that I get is **"The method checkSelfPermission(MyActivity, String) is undefined by the type ContextCompat** In my imports: `import android.support.v7.app.*`    `import android.support.v7.appcompat.*`    `import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat`

Comment: @neuman8 I will advise to get Android Studio. Eclipse isn't support anymore for Android development.

Comment: I solved my own issue.  I was not importing the new version of android-support-v4.jar as well.  Google has made many changes to that .jar since the last time I pulled it into my project. BTW, answering with "move to Android Studio" isn't very helpful, because for various reasons we can't move to AS.

Comment: @neuman8 I am sorry if it wasn't helpful. Here's Google's own words in June 2015 "Support for the ADT in Eclipse has ended. You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible." http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

Comment: so are you talking about v4 or v7? you said you need v4 but compile v7. which is it? I have v4 and have this issue, would v7 fix it?

Comment: @BorisGafurov I should be support-v4. The answer had been updated in the past, I changed it now. You need latest version of support-v4 which is 23.4.0 currently.

Comment: `support-v4:27.1.0` appears to be broken. I had to revert to `26.1.0` to be able to use `ContextCompat`

Comment: @behelit `ContextCompat` has been made protected starting from version 25.0.0 https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive

Answer (score 46):

```
androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
```

from AndroidX dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

Comment: For newer versions use `implementation` and not `compile`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this and a few more posts helped me.
With Android studio you have multiple Gradle files.

I got my code to work by adding the dependencies section into Gradle (Module : Library) or the file that has "android {" ...

```
dependencies {
        // other stuff here
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
        // update the 23.0.0 to latest version available
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android gradle plugin 3.0.1, add google() to your allProjects repositories in the build.gradle file (project level) then sync

like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        ....
        //other repos
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to build.gradle(Module:App) under dependencies resolved the problem

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
```

Comment: change compile to implementation. compile has been deprecated and replaced by implementation in recent version of android studio.