# Why I can not import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat in my AndroidStudio project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my project, I want to use `getDrawable();` method from `ContextCompat` class, like this (almost at the end of this code):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle);

        TextView tvTitulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_valorTitulo);
        TextView tvIsbn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_valorIsbn);
        TextView tvFecha = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_valorFecha);
        ImageView ivLibro = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_libro);
        Button btnAceptar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_ok);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getExtras() != null){
            isbn = intent.getStringExtra("isbn");
            fechaPublicacion = intent.getStringExtra("fechaPublicacion");
            titulo = intent.getStringExtra("titulo");
            idImagen = intent.getIntExtra("imagen", R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            tvTitulo.setText(titulo);
            tvIsbn.setText(isbn);
            tvFecha.setText(fechaPublicacion);
            Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, idImagen);
            ivLibro.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

But this line `Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, idImagen);` gives me an error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'ContextCompat'

The stackoverflow.com user @Mark F did a similar question like this before ([Mark F question in SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31733044/5401584)), and an user replied, even @Mark F made a YouTube video, but I did what the video says and I can not achieve import the respective library to use this class.

I just added `import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;` at the top, but this does not work.

I added this to my build.gradle file like the user replied to Mark F but still not working

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
}
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try building the project

Comment: `23.0.0` is a bit old. It is possible that `ContextCompat` did not exist then. Usually, for new app development, you use the latest Android Support Library versions (presently `25.1.1`).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, guys. I was doing what both mention, but still not working. Anyway, thanks for help.