# checkSelfPermission: How to do it prior to API 22

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to port my app from API 22 to API 26. Several API calls are failing (e.g. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, etc.). I believe it is due to the new runtime permission model wherein permissions are not granted EVEN if they are in the manifest.

So I tried to do the right thing, namely using checkSelfPermission() and requesting the permission if denied.

My problem is that checkSelfPermission is not available before API 23 and my minSdkVersion is lower than that so Android Studio flags it as an error.

I'm now stuck between rock & hard place: If I raise my minSdkVersion to 23, I'll break the app for many existing customers.  If I lower my targetSdkVersion below API 23 to avoid the problem, Google Play won't accept it.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check permissions only for API >= 23.For API < 21 will use [install-time requests](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)

Comment: You can still check if the user has accepted the required permission below API 23. `checkSelfPermission` will return True on older devices anyway.

Comment: That worked. Apparently the "error" I got was only a warning. checkSelfPermission worked on API level 22 and returned true as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) in the v4 support library (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733044/cannot-resolve-contextcompat-in-android)). This is a "compatibility layer", so that single function will work on all versions of Android.