# Flutter Plugin Development - Unable to use ContextCompat in my Project

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to develop a flutter plugin for android permissions. It through this  error

[image]

I already search other different question here but none is solving my problem

have a look at this screenshot too 
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIzMj.png)

this means I am unable to access .support class

I already tried to add

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
                               or
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:28.0.0'
```

My Gradle file looks like this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

after upgrading my plugin to Android X it through these errors

[Error After Upgrading to Android X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJlAi.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Resolve ContextCompat in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733044/cannot-resolve-contextcompat-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try migrating to AndroidX (if not already there) and change the support dependency to:

```
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
```

Comment: can you tell me how to migrate my flutter package to Android X?

Comment: In Android Studio, Refactor > Migrate to Android X.

Comment: I just update my question related to android X error

Comment: Upgrade the gradle plugin as suggested